# Query for a rectangular area when using geography data type (DbGeography)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, google-maps, spatial

I'm querying a table in SQL Server to show results on Google Maps, and I'm using Entity Framework and DbGeography data types on the server application.

Simply, I get the map bounds from the Google Maps instance, construct a DbGeography instance from it using something like this:

```
var wkt = string.Format("POLYGON(({0} {1}, {0} {2}, {3} {2}, {3} {1}, {0} {1}))", EastLng, NorthLat, SouthLat, WestLng);
var bounds = DbGeography.FromText(wkt);
```

And then query the database using this (as a part of a larger query):

```
dbset.Where(i => bounds.Intersects(l.GeographicLocation));
```

This works fine, and I actually have it working in production for a while. Today I noticed that sometimes some results don't show up correctly on the map.

After some investigation, I realized that it is because the earth's curvature; Google Maps uses a rectangular projection of the earth, but what when I create a rectangular polygon, it means a shape like this (copied from SQL Server Management Studio, from the query that was running):

[image: Boundary projection]

The effect is increased when looking at maps of very large areas (zooming out). But when I zoom in, the effect of earth's curvature decreases and query seems to work fine.

What I need to do, is to basically query the DB for all points that lie within a Lat/Lng boundary. Is there a way to do this?

---

EDIT:

This is the complete code that I'm using to create a DbGeography instance:

```
public class LatLngBounds
{
    // ...

    public DbGeography ToDbGeography()
    {
        return DbGeographyUtil.CreatePolygon(string.Format("POLYGON(({0} {1}, {0} {2}, {3} {2}, {3} {1}, {0} {1}))", EastLng, NorthLat, SouthLat, WestLng));
    }
}


public static class DbGeographyUtil
{
    public static DbGeography CreatePolygon(string wktString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(wktString))
            return null;

        var sqlGeography = SqlGeography.STGeomFromText(new SqlChars(wktString), DbGeography.DefaultCoordinateSystemId).MakeValid();

        var invertedSqlGeography = sqlGeography.ReorientObject();
        if (sqlGeography.STArea() > invertedSqlGeography.STArea())
        {
            sqlGeography = invertedSqlGeography;
        }

        return DbSpatialServices.Default.GeographyFromProviderValue(sqlGeography);
    }

}
```

---

EDIT 2:

The coordinates coming out of Google Maps in the above example is:

- North East: Lat=53.6 Lng=92.5
- South West: Lat=35.0 Lng=21.2

This is a part of the query that was running, that I captured using SQL Server Profiler:

```
declare @p4 sys.geography
set @p4=convert(sys.geography,0xE6100000010405000000463E933FAFD64A40070000006E3F354061E412079A894140070000006E3F354061E412079A894140020000808B245740463E933FAFD64A40020000808B245740463E933FAFD64A40070000006E3F354001000000020000000001000000FFFFFFFF0000000003)

SELECT @p4;
```

(I added the `SELECT` to see how it looks like, and resulted in the image above)

Comment: If you use the geography data type, or geometry with srid of 4326, and define a box in geographic coordinates, you won't have any problem. I'm not sure I follow the Google Maps part -- it is  very simple projection, and the y value is essentially just a linear function of latitude, I can't see why you would get the curvature you are seeing. A given line of latitude will map to the same y coordinate in spherical mercator (Google Maps). There are other projections where this is not the case, such as Transverse Mercator, as used in UK, but not in this case.

Comment: @JohnBarça Please see my edit. All my types in the database is geography. I suppose the lines are curved because the shortest line that connects the South East and South West points is not parallel to the equator, and what I remember from "geography" type definition (in comparison to geometry) is that it accounts for such conditions.

Comment: Could you give an example of the coordinates as they are coming from Google Maps, which are being used to generate the image above?

Comment: @JohnBarça Please see the "EDIT 2" :)

Comment: Sorry to be obtuse, but how are you getting the coordinates out of Google Maps. My understanding is that Google Maps uses spherical mercator, which is in meters.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with Google Maps, this will happen if I want to query for any Lat/Lng bounds. But here's what I do: I use `var mapBounds = map.getBounds();` and then later `mapBounds.getNorthEast().lat()` etc. to get the bounds.

Comment: Basically, my question is how can I query geography data type for something like `Lat between X and Y && Lng between X and Y`. Creating a rectangular polygon won't do it, as I've shown above.

Comment: I still have no idea how you managed to produce that curved rectangle, but I assure you it has nothing to do with going from Google Maps SRID, 3857, to lat/lon (4326). You could get a trapezoid, sure, but a horizontal line in 3857 corresponds to a horizontal line in 4326. The meridians will curve, but not the parallels. Perhaps it might be easier if you gave a point and a rectangle (in 4326) that isn't working as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to solve this by using DbGeometry instead of DbGeography

```
var boundsAsGeometry = DbGeometry.FromText(bounds.AsText(), bounds.CoordinateSystemId);

dbset.Where(x => boundsAsGeometry.Intersects(DbGeometry.FromText(x.GeographicLocation.AsText(), x.GeographicLocation.CoordinateSystemId)));
```

Be aware that this will not use the existing db index for the GeographicLocation field if you have that.